# Indenting second line of list in paragraph element (not UL or OL)

Tags: html, css

I have a table with the following structure:

```css
html {
  width: 400px;  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Description:</td>
      <td style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
Some text which could be quite long with some 'simple' lists created by the user like this:
- Point 1
- Point 2
- Point 3
- Another point which is a bit longer than the previous one
- Point 4
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I would view this in the browsers, on a screen with a small width, one of the bullet points will wrap to the new line and start at the beginning of this new line.

Ideally I want this bullet point to have the same indentation as the line before so both lines of text of the same bullet point will have the same indentation.

In case you're wondering, the reason why there is no ordered or unordered list element is because the user is limited to using a simple textarea to enter their content.

Could anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not trivially possible to have an indentation like this. Not unless you allow the users to enter _some_ markup. Maybe you need some javascript based rich textbox framework.

Comment: That's where I was afraid of. To be honest, I thought it wasn't possible myself either because I think there is no way for the browser to know if it is a real (un)ordered list or just some regular text. Until now it looks like a JavaScript Text Editor would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the code be like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Description:</td>
      <td style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
Some text which could be quite long with some 'simple' lists created by the user like this:
<ul>
<li>Point 1</li>
<li>Point 2</li>
<li>Point 3</li>
<li>Another point which is a bit longer than the previous one</li>
<li>Point 4</li>
</ul>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to use proper `ul and li` tags instead of `-`.

**EDIT**

If you are willing to populate the value from some `text-area` field, then you might implement **WYSIWYG** text editors like **TinyMCE**, **CKeditor** .

Comment: _In case you're wondering, the reason why there is no ordered or unordered list element is because the user is limited to using a simple textarea to enter their content._ I guess the text in the `<td>` comes from some user's plaintext input.

Comment: @JohnBupit In that case, he should use some `Text Editor` feature for his `text-area`.

Comment: Right now there is no real text editor available and I wanted to know if it possible without one.

Comment: What you could do, is offer the user some special tags to use for an indentation? and than maybe do a str_replace and replace it with a span with a class, and then style that as an indentation?

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks. I will keep that one in mind.